# Vlocity/Salesforce Industries Cloud: Product Attribute of type Lookup?

Tags: lookup, vlocity, attribute, energy-and-utilities, industry-cloud

Is it supported to create an Attribute of type "Lookup" in Salesforce Industries CPQ? I see that for example, Picklists, text and number are supported but i don't see Lookup to be supported. Is it feasible out-of-the-box or with low-code development to implement an Attribute where user selects an sObject record from a Salesforce object?